# Convert Bytes to Floating Point Numbers?

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a binary file that I have to parse and I'm using Python. Is there a way to take 4 bytes and convert it to a single precision floating point number?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('f', 3.141592654)
b'\xdb\x0fI@'
>>> struct.unpack('f', b'\xdb\x0fI@')
(3.1415927410125732,)
>>> struct.pack('4f', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x80@'
```

Comment: This only works for 4 or 8 byte floats. What about 10-byte floats?

Comment: I agree with @dplass, what about other floats. And, why is there a comma at the end of this string?

Comment: @startec The question was about 4-byte floats. Which string ends with a comma? Only the tuple from `struct.unpack` has a comma.

Comment: ok, and what about the comparison of the two numbers?
    `>>> import struct`
    `>>> a=3.141592654`
    `>>> print a`
    `3.141592654`
    `>>> a_packed=struct.pack('f', a)`
    `>>> b=struct.unpack('f', a_packed)[0]`
    `>>> print b`
    `3.14159274101`
    `>>> assert a==b, "A non B"`
    `Traceback (most recent call last):`
    ` File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
    `AssertionError: A non B`

Comment: @PetrKrampl accuracy of C `float` (single, 4 bytes) and C `double` (double, 8 bytes). Python `float` is really C `double`. Whatever the accuracy of storing `3.141592654` as a C `double`, it's lost when it's converted to a C `float` (by struct.pack) and then back to C `double` (Python extracts the 4-bytes as a C `float` and then converts the result back to a C `double`/Python `float`). This applies to all implementations of Python that use IEEE754 floating point numbers (CPython does; anyway, I don't know of any non-IEEE754-conformant Python implementation on any system).

Comment: Note: to view the individual bytes of the bytearray (indicated by b'), use `list()`. Ex: `list(struct.pack('f', 3.141592654))` returns a list of the individual bytes as `[219, 15, 73, 64]`. This is very handy.

Answer (score 21):

Just a little addition, if you want a float number as output from the unpack method instead of a tuple just write

```
>>> import struct
>>> [x] = struct.unpack('f', b'\xdb\x0fI@')
>>> x
3.1415927410125732
```

If you have more floats then just write

```
>>> import struct
>>> [x,y] = struct.unpack('ff', b'\xdb\x0fI@\x0b\x01I4')
>>> x
3.1415927410125732
>>> y
1.8719963179592014e-07
>>>
```

Comment: Alternately you can reference the list position on the RHS

`x = struct.unpack('f', b'\xdb\x0fI@')[0]`

Answer (score 4):

I would add a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Just to add some info. If you have a byte buffer containing X amount of floats, the syntax for unpacking would be:

```
struct.unpack('Xf', ...)
```

If the values are doubles the unpacking would be:

```
struct.unpack('Xd', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment: let's say you are receiving a float variable via MODBUS communication protocol (2 registers, 1 int each), you can convert the message with:

floatvar = struct.unpack('f',int1.to_bytes(2,'big')+int2.to_bytes(2,'big')).

*note MODBUS is big Endian