# How Does One Read Bytes from File in Python

Tags: python, id3

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python) question, I am trying to read in an ID3v2 tag header and am having trouble figuring out how to get individual bytes in python.

I first read all ten bytes into a string.  I then want to parse out the individual pieces of information.

I can grab the two version number chars in the string, but then I have no idea how to take those two chars and get an integer out of them.

The struct package seems to be what I want, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code so-far (I am very new to python btw...so take it easy on me):

```
def __init__(self, ten_byte_string):
        self.whole_string = ten_byte_string
        self.file_identifier = self.whole_string[:3]
        self.major_version = struct.pack('x', self.whole_string[3:4]) #this 
        self.minor_version = struct.pack('x', self.whole_string[4:5]) # and this
        self.flags = self.whole_string[5:6]
        self.len = self.whole_string[6:10]
```

Printing out any value except is obviously crap because they are not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a string, with 2 bytes that you wish to interpret as a 16 bit integer, you can do so by:

```
>>> s = '\0\x02'
>>> struct.unpack('>H', s)
(2,)
```

Note that the > is for big-endian (the largest part of the integer comes first).  This is the format id3 tags use.

For other sizes of integer, you use different format codes.  eg. "i" for a signed 32 bit integer.  See help(struct) for details.

You can also unpack several elements at once.  eg for 2 unsigned shorts, followed by a signed 32 bit value:

```
>>> a,b,c = struct.unpack('>HHi', some_string)
```

Going by your code, you are looking for (in order):

- a 3 char string
- 2 single byte values (major and minor version)
- a 1 byte flags variable
- a 32 bit length quantity

The format string for this would be:

```
ident, major, minor, flags, len = struct.unpack('>3sBBBI', ten_byte_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why write your own?  (Assuming you haven't checked out these other options.)  There's a couple options out there for reading in ID3 tag info from MP3s in Python.  Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python#102285) over at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python) question.

Comment: I did see them.  But this is actually for a project for school and we decided that we would write our own parser.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to recommend the `struct` package but then you said you had tried it. Try this:

```
self.major_version = struct.unpack('H', self.whole_string[3:5])
```

The `pack()` function convers Python data types to bits, and the `unpack()` function converts bits to Python data types.

Comment: for 'H', you'll need to use a 2-byte slice.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that. I'll fix my example so it works, but yours is a better answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to read in an ID3v2 tag header

FWIW, there's [already a module](http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/) for this.