# What's the equivalent of C#'s GetBytes() in Python?

Tags: c#, python, encryption, aes

I have

```
byte[] request = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParams);
```

in a C# AES encryption only class that I'm converting to Python. Can anyone tell me the Python 2.5 equivalent(I'm using this on google app engine?

Example inputs:

**request_params:** &r=p&playerid=6263017 (or a combination of query strings)
**dev_key:** GK1FzK12iPYKE9Kt
**dev_iv:** E2I21NEwsC9RdSN2
**dev_id:** 12

**Python function:**

```
def Encrypt(self, request_params, dev_key, dev_iv, dev_id):

    data_bytes = request_params.encode("utf-8")
    block_size = 16
    mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    assert len(dev_key) == block_size and len(dev_iv) == block_size

    pad_char = '0'
    pad_length = block_size - len(data_bytes) % block_size
    padded_data_bytes = data_bytes + pad_length * pad_char

    encrypted_bytes = dev_iv + AES.new(dev_key, mode, dev_iv).encrypt(padded_data_bytes)
    base64_encrypted_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(encrypted_bytes))
    request_uri = "http://api.blackoutrugby.com/?d=" + dev_id + "&er=" + base64_encrypted_string
    #http://api.blackoutrugby.com/?d=19&er=RTJJNTFORXdzQzNSZFNObNerdsGhiNoeue6c3mzed4Ty1YE-gTlVJVXHz05uPT-8
    # output from this Python code, it's incorrect
    #http://api.blackoutrugby.com/?d=19&er=16t2waGI2h657pzebN53hPr4kEjOzgsOEZiycDwPXR4=
    # correct output from C# code
    return request_uri
```

**C# Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace BlackoutRugbyPOC.Controllers {
    public class BlackoutRugbyAPI {
        public static string Request(string requestParams, string devKey, string devIV, string devID) {
            // Create an unencrypted request as an array of bytes
            byte[] request = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParams);
            byte[] key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(devKey);
            byte[] iv = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(devIV);

            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Get the transformer from the AES Encryptor
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor();

            // Use the transformer to encrypt our request
            byte[] result = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(request, 0, request.Length);
            aes.Clear();

            // Encode to base64
            string encryptedRequest = Convert.ToBase64String(result, 0, result.Length);

            // Send request to API
            string requestUri = "http://api.blackoutrugby.com/?d=" + devID + "&er=" + encryptedRequest;
            string xmlResponse = getWebResponse(requestUri);
            return XmlToJson(xmlResponse);
        }

        private static string getWebResponse(string url) {
            string html = "";

            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return html;
        }

        public static string XmlToJson(string xml) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("XML Input");

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            try {
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
            } catch {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Input could not be loaded into XML Document");
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Why are you using a string as key/IV? I guess you're only using A-Za-z0-9?! That would reduce the key strength to 95 bits. BTW `PaddingMode.Zeros` refers to binary zeroes, not to the character '0' as in your Python code. Use "\x00" instead to produce a binary byte with the value zero.

Comment: The key and IV are supplied by the API service (blackoutrugby.com) which requires me to use AES on the requests I send to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does One Read Bytes from File in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150532/how-does-one-read-bytes-from-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know where you got the following code from

```
data_bytes = str.encode(request_params)
key_bytes = str.encode(dev_key)
iv_bytes = str.encode(dev_iv)
```

but you should know that it is equivalent to the following:

```
data_bytes = request_params.encode("ascii")
key_bytes = dev_key.encode("ascii")
iv_bytes = dev_iv.encode("ascii")
```

which means that non-ASCII characters in any of the three variables will cause an error (I hope you don't make up an AES key of ASCII characters only?).

In Python 2.x, `str` objects (`byte[]` in C#) are bytes and `unicode` objects (`string` in C#) are for text. This confusing fact was changed in Python 3.x, by the way.
That means if `request_params` is a Unicode object, you should encode it as UTF-8, and if it's a `str` object, you should assume (or check) that it is already encoded as UTF-8. So it might be something like:

```
if isinstance(request_params, unicode):
    data_bytes = request_params.encode("utf-8")
else:
    request_params.decode("utf-8") # optional check whether it is correct UTF-8
    data_bytes = request_params
```

As for key/IV, they will always be *binary* data (e.g. 16 bytes for AES-128), not text. So they don't have a character encoding. Remove those two lines of code and probably replace them with

```
assert len(dev_key) == block_size and len(dev_iv) == block_size
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     buffer = file.read(bytes)
```