# How to convert a string of bytes into an int?

Tags: python, arrays, string

How can I convert a string of bytes into an int in python?

Say like this: `'y\xcc\xa6\xbb'`

I came up with a clever/stupid way of doing it:

```
sum(ord(c) << (i * 8) for i, c in enumerate('y\xcc\xa6\xbb'[::-1]))
```

I know there has to be something builtin or in the standard library that does this more simply...

This is different from [converting a string of hex digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python) for which you can use int(xxx, 16), but instead I want to convert a string of actual byte values.

UPDATE:

I kind of like James' answer a little better because it doesn't require importing another module, but Greg's method is faster:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('struct.unpack("<L", "y\xcc\xa6\xbb")[0]', 'import struct').timeit()
0.36242198944091797
>>> Timer("int('y\xcc\xa6\xbb'.encode('hex'), 16)").timeit()
1.1432669162750244
```

My hacky method:

```
>>> Timer("sum(ord(c) << (i * 8) for i, c in enumerate('y\xcc\xa6\xbb'[::-1]))").timeit()
2.8819329738616943
```

FURTHER UPDATE:

Someone asked in comments what's the problem with importing another module. Well, importing a module isn't necessarily cheap, take a look:

```
>>> Timer("""import struct\nstruct.unpack(">L", "y\xcc\xa6\xbb")[0]""").timeit()
0.98822188377380371
```

Including the cost of importing the module negates almost all of the advantage that this method has. I believe that this will only include the expense of importing it once for the entire benchmark run; look what happens when I force it to reload every time:

```
>>> Timer("""reload(struct)\nstruct.unpack(">L", "y\xcc\xa6\xbb")[0]""", 'import struct').timeit()
68.474128007888794
```

Needless to say, if you're doing a lot of executions of this method per one import than this becomes proportionally less of an issue. It's also probably i/o cost rather than cpu so it may depend on the capacity and load characteristics of the particular machine.

Comment: and importing something from the standard lib is bad, why?

Comment: andyway, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python

Comment: your "further update" is weird... why would you import the module so often?

Comment: I know this is old question. But if you want to keep your comparison upto date for other people: Mechanical snail's answer (`int.from_bytes`) out-performed `struct.unpack` on my computer. Next to being more readable imo.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can also use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) module to do this:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<L", "y\xcc\xa6\xbb")[0]
3148270713L
```

Comment: Warning: "L" is actually 8 bytes (not 4) in 64 bit Python builds, so this might fail there.

Comment: Rafał: Not really, since Greg was using <, according to the docs L is standard size (4) "when the format string starts with one of '<', '>', '!' or '='." http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: This answer doesn't work for arbitrary-length binary strings.

Comment: Types have specific sizes, it'll never work for arbitrary-length binary strings. You could set up a for loop to handle that if you know the type of each item.

Comment: This is a good answer *as long as* the integer you are creating is a long or shorter. If you are converting something longer than 64 bits, the suggestion below (in.from_bytes, Python 3.2 or higher) is much better.

Comment: this is the best answer for python 2.x

Comment: "L" is actually uint32 (4 bytes). If as in my case you need 8 bytes, use "Q"-->uint64. Also note that "l"-->int32 and q-->int64

Comment: I used q for long long which is 8 bytes signed while Q for unsigned long long. print struct.unpack("<Q", packed)[0]. This code is for python 2.7

Answer (score 360):

In Python 3.2 and later, use

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'y\xcc\xa6\xbb', byteorder='big')
2043455163
```

or

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'y\xcc\xa6\xbb', byteorder='little')
3148270713
```

according to the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your byte-string.

This also works for bytestring-integers of arbitrary length, and for two's-complement signed integers by specifying `signed=True`. See the [docs for `from_bytes`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

Comment: @eri how much slower? I used to use struct but converted to int.from_bytes when I went to py3. I am calling this method every ms as I am receiving serial data so any speedup is welcome. I have been looking at this

Comment: @Naib, for `os.urandom(4)` bytes **1.4 µs**(struct) vs **2.3 µs**(int.from_bytes) on my cpu. python 3.5.2

Comment: @eri I resurrected a timeit script i used to evaluate a couple of CRC methods. Four runs 1) struct 2) int.from_bytes 3) as #1 but cython compiled, 4) as #2 but cython compiled. 330ns for struct, 1.14us for int (cython gave maybe 20ns speedup in both...) looks like I am switching back :) this isn't premature optimisation, I have been hitting some nasty bottlenecks, especially with a million samples to post-process and have been knocking parts off.

Answer (score 68):

As Greg said, you can use struct if you are dealing with binary values, but if you just have a "hex number" but in byte format you might want to just convert it like:

```
s = 'y\xcc\xa6\xbb'
num = int(s.encode('hex'), 16)
```

...this is the same as:

```
num = struct.unpack(">L", s)[0]
```

...except it'll work for any number of bytes.

Comment: what exactly is the difference between "binary values" and a "'hex number' but in byte format"???????

Comment: See "help struct". Eg. "001122334455".decode('hex') cannot be converted to a number using struct.

Comment: By the way, this answer assumes that the integer is encoded in big-endian byte order. For little-endian order, do: `int(''.join(reversed(s)).encode('hex'), 16)`

Comment: good but this is going to be slow!  Guess that doesn't really matter if you're coding in Python.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following function to convert data between int, hex and bytes.

```
def bytes2int(str):
 return int(str.encode('hex'), 16)

def bytes2hex(str):
 return '0x'+str.encode('hex')

def int2bytes(i):
 h = int2hex(i)
 return hex2bytes(h)

def int2hex(i):
 return hex(i)

def hex2int(h):
 if len(h) > 1 and h[0:2] == '0x':
  h = h[2:]

 if len(h) % 2:
  h = "0" + h

 return int(h, 16)

def hex2bytes(h):
 if len(h) > 1 and h[0:2] == '0x':
  h = h[2:]

 if len(h) % 2:
  h = "0" + h

 return h.decode('hex')
```

Source: http://opentechnotes.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/convert-values-to-from-integer-hex.html

Answer (score 6):

```
import array
integerValue = array.array("I", 'y\xcc\xa6\xbb')[0]
```

Warning: the above is strongly platform-specific. Both the "I" specifier and the endianness of the string->int conversion are dependent on your particular Python implementation. But if you want to convert many integers/strings at once, then the array module does it quickly.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.x, you could use the format specifiers `<B` for unsigned bytes, and `<b` for signed bytes with `struct.unpack`/`struct.pack`.

E.g:

Let `x` = `'\xff\x10\x11'`

```
data_ints = struct.unpack('<' + 'B'*len(x), x) # [255, 16, 17]
```

And:

```
data_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'B'*len(data_ints), *data_ints) # '\xff\x10\x11'
```

*That `*` is required!*

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters for a list of the format specifiers.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> reduce(lambda s, x: s*256 + x, bytearray("y\xcc\xa6\xbb"))
2043455163
```

Test 1: inverse:

```
>>> hex(2043455163)
'0x79cca6bb'
```

Test 2: Number of bytes > 8:

```
>>> reduce(lambda s, x: s*256 + x, bytearray("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"))
338822822454978555838225329091068225L
```

Test 3: Increment by one:

```
>>> reduce(lambda s, x: s*256 + x, bytearray("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAB"))
338822822454978555838225329091068226L
```

Test 4: Append one byte, say 'A':

```
>>> reduce(lambda s, x: s*256 + x, bytearray("AAAAAAAAAAAAAABA"))
86738642548474510294585684247313465921L
```

Test 5: Divide by 256:

```
>>> reduce(lambda s, x: s*256 + x, bytearray("AAAAAAAAAAAAAABA"))/256
338822822454978555838225329091068226L
```

Result equals the result of Test 4, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to find a solution for arbitrary length byte sequences that would work under Python 2.x. Finally I wrote this one, it's a bit hacky because it performs a string conversion, but it works.

## Function for Python 2.x, arbitrary length

```
def signedbytes(data):
    """Convert a bytearray into an integer, considering the first bit as
    sign. The data must be big-endian."""
    negative = data[0] & 0x80 > 0

    if negative:
        inverted = bytearray(~d % 256 for d in data)
        return -signedbytes(inverted) - 1

    encoded = str(data).encode('hex')
    return int(encoded, 16)
```

This function has two requirements:

- The input `data` needs to be a `bytearray`. You may call the function like this:

  ```
  s = 'y\xcc\xa6\xbb'
  n = signedbytes(s)
  ```
- The data needs to be big-endian. In case you have a little-endian value, you should reverse it first:

  ```
  n = signedbytes(s[::-1])
  ```

Of course, this should be used only if arbitrary length is needed. Otherwise, stick with more standard ways (e.g. `struct`).

Answer (score 1):

int.from_bytes is the best solution if you are at version >=3.2.
The "struct.unpack" solution requires a string so it will not apply to arrays of bytes.
Here is another solution:

```
def bytes2int( tb, order='big'):
    if order == 'big': seq=[0,1,2,3]
    elif order == 'little': seq=[3,2,1,0]
    i = 0
    for j in seq: i = (i<<8)+tb[j]
    return i
```

hex( bytes2int( [0x87, 0x65, 0x43, 0x21])) returns '0x87654321'.

It handles big and little endianness and is easily modifiable for 8 bytes

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above using `unpack` function of **struct** is a good way. If you want to implement your own function there is an another solution:

```
def bytes_to_int(bytes):
    result = 0
    for b in bytes:
        result = result * 256 + int(b)
return result
```

Comment: This doesn't work for negative number that was converted to bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you can easily convert a byte string into a list of integers (0..255) by

```
>>> list(b'y\xcc\xa6\xbb')
[121, 204, 166, 187]
```

Answer (score 0):

A decently speedy method utilizing array.array I've been using for some time:

predefined variables:

```
offset = 0
size = 4
big = True # endian
arr = array('B')
arr.fromstring("\x00\x00\xff\x00") # 5 bytes (encoding issues) [0, 0, 195, 191, 0]
```

to int: (read)

```
val = 0
for v in arr[offset:offset+size][::pow(-1,not big)]: val = (val<<8)|v
```

from int: (write)

```
val = 16384
arr[offset:offset+size] = \
    array('B',((val>>(i<<3))&255 for i in range(size)))[::pow(-1,not big)]
```

It's possible these could be faster though.

EDIT:
For some numbers, here's a performance test (Anaconda 2.3.0) showing stable averages on read in comparison to `reduce()`:

```
========================= byte array to int.py =========================
5000 iterations; threshold of min + 5000ns:
______________________________________code___|_______min______|_______max______|_______avg______|_efficiency
⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⢀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⢰⠀⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⢀⡇⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⠀⢸⡀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⡇⠀⠀⢠⠀⢰⠀⢸⠀
⣿⣦⣴⣰⣦⣿⣾⣧⣤⣷⣦⣤⣶⣾⣿⣦⣼⣶⣷⣶⣸⣴⣤⣀⣾⣾⣄⣤⣾⡆⣾⣿⣿⣶⣾⣾⣶⣿⣤⣾⣤⣤⣴⣼⣾⣼⣴⣤⣼⣷⣆⣴⣴⣿⣾⣷⣧⣶⣼⣴⣿⣶⣿⣶
    val = 0 \nfor v in arr: val = (val<<8)|v |     5373.848ns |   850009.965ns |     ~8649.64ns |  62.128%
⡇⠀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⠀⠀⣠⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⡆⠀⡆⢰⠀⠀⡆⠀⡄⠀⠀⠀⢠⢀⣼⠀⠀⡇⣠⣸⣤⡇⠀⡆⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠀⢠⣿⠀⠀⢠⠀⠀⢸⢠⠀⡀
⣧⣶⣶⣾⣶⣷⣴⣿⣾⡇⣤⣶⣿⣸⣿⣶⣶⣶⣶⣧⣷⣼⣷⣷⣷⣿⣦⣴⣧⣄⣷⣠⣷⣶⣾⣸⣿⣶⣶⣷⣿⣿⣿⣷⣧⣷⣼⣦⣶⣾⣿⣾⣼⣿⣿⣶⣶⣼⣦⣼⣾⣿⣶⣷
                  val = reduce( shift, arr ) |     6489.921ns |  5094212.014ns |   ~12040.269ns |  53.902%
```

This is a raw performance test, so the endian pow-flip is left out.
The `shift` function shown applies the same shift-oring operation as the for loop, and `arr` is just `array.array('B',[0,0,255,0])` as it has the fastest iterative performance next to `dict`.

I should probably also note efficiency is measured by accuracy to the average time.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Python a simple way is:

```py
int(b'hello world'.hex(), 16)
```