# Convert little endian string to integer

Tags: python, numpy, wav

I have read samples out of a wave file using the wave module, but it gives the samples as a string, it's out of wave so it's little endian (for example, `\x00`).

What is the easiest way to convert this into a python integer, or a numpy.int16 type? (It will eventually become a numpy.int16, so going directly there is fine).

Code needs to work on little endian and big endian processors.

Comment: The general case is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `struct` module converts packed data to Python values, and vice-versa.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("<h", "\x00\x05")
(1280,)
>>> struct.unpack("<h", "\x00\x06")
(1536,)
>>> struct.unpack("<h", "\x01\x06")
(1537,)
```

"h" means a short int, or 16-bit int. "<" means use little-endian.

Comment: For python3 you need to convert your string first to bytes `struct.unpack("<h", bytes("\x00\x06", "utf8"))`

Answer (score 12):

[`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) is fine if you have to convert one or a small number of 2-byte strings to integers, but [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array) and `numpy` itself are better options.  Specifically, [numpy.fromstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) (called with the appropriate `dtype` argument) can directly convert the bytes from your string to an array of (whatever that `dtype` is).  (If `numpy.little_endian` is false, you'll then have to swap the bytes -- see [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg02747.html) for more discussion, but basically you'll want to call the `byteswap` method on the array object you just built with `fromstring`).

Comment: This is really good to know as well, I'm going to go with the struct solution though, so that I don't need to worry about correcting endianess manually.

Comment: If you're in no hurry, or have very few data points, that's fine. Otherwise, you _can_ codify endianness as a string as part of the `dtype` (I don't know the details offhand, though).

Answer (score 1):

[Kevin Burke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698048/8008041) to this question works great when your binary string represents a single short integer, but if your string holds binary data representing multiple integers, you will need to add an additional 'h' for each additional integer that the string represents.

**For Python 2**

Convert Little Endian String that represents **2 integers**

```
import struct
iValues = struct.unpack("<hh", "\x00\x04\x01\x05")
print(iValues)
```

Output: (1024, 1281)

Convert Little Endian String that represents **3 integers**

```
import struct
iValues = struct.unpack("<hhh", "\x00\x04\x01\x05\x03\x04")
print(iValues)
```

Output: (1024, 1281, 1027)

Obviously, it's not realistic to always guess how many "h" characters are needed, so:

```
import struct

# A string that holds some unknown quantity of integers in binary form
strBinary_Values = "\x00\x04\x01\x05\x03\x04"

# Calculate the number of integers that are represented by binary string data
iQty_of_Values = len(strBinary_Values)/2

# Produce the string of required "h" values
h = "h" * int(iQty_of_Values)

iValues = struct.unpack("<"+h, strBinary_Values)
print(iValues)
```

Output: (1024, 1281, 1027)

**For Python 3**

```
import struct

# A string that holds some unknown quantity of integers in binary form
strBinary_Values = "\x00\x04\x01\x05\x03\x04"

# Calculate the number of integers that are represented by binary string data
iQty_of_Values = len(strBinary_Values)/2

# Produce the string of required "h" values
h = "h" * int(iQty_of_Values)

iValues = struct.unpack("<"+h, bytes(strBinary_Values, "utf8"))
print(iValues)
```

Output: (1024, 1281, 1027)

Answer (score 0):

```py
int(value[::-1].hex(), 16)
```

By example:

```py
value = b'\xfd\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
print(int(value[::-1].hex(), 16))
65533
```

`[::-1]` invert the values (little endian), `.hex()` trabnsform to hex literal, `int(,16)` transform from hex literal to int base16.