# zipfile cant handle some type of zip data?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I came up over this problem while trying to decompress a zip file.

-- `zipfile.is_zipfile(my_file)` always returns False, even though the UNIX command unzip handles it just fine. Also, when trying to do `zipfile.ZipFile(path/file_handle_to_path)` I get the same error

-- the `file` command returns `Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract` and using `less` on the file it shows:

```
PKZIP for iSeries by PKWARE
 Length      Method Size      Cmpr Date       Time  CRC-32    Name
 2113482674  Defl:S 204502989  90% 2010-11-01 08:39 2cee662e  myfile.txt
 2113482674         204502989  90%                            1 file
```

Any ideas how can I go around this issue ? It would be nice if I could make python's `zipfile` work since I already have some unit tests that I'll have to drop if I'll switch to running `subprocess.call("unzip")`

Comment: `import os` and tell us, what `os.path.exists(my_file)` returns.

Comment: @hyperboreean - just thought you could have a problem with the filename, since `zipfile.is_zipfile` returns `False` for non-existing files too.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083235/problem-with-unzipping-file. Unfortunately, that poster didn't receive a solution. :(

Comment: What is the filesize, more than 1GB?

Comment: Could it be this: http://bugs.python.org/issue1757072 ?

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: decompressed it's 2GB. Compressed it's 196 MB.

Comment: You thought "iSeries" didn't need more than a casual reference? Are you running in a Linux partition (with what version of Python?) or under OS/400?

Comment: @John Machin: python2.6 (2.6.2-2.6.6) they all act the same. Running on linux machines. Thanks!

Comment: @hyperboreean: Could you post a zip demonstrating this problem somewhere? With some data to test with, it might be easier to pinpoint the actual problem.

Answer (score 8):

Run into the same issue on my files and was able to solve it. I'm not sure how they were generated, like in the above example. They all had trailing data in the end ignored by both Windows by 7z and failing python's zipfile.

This is the code to solve the issue:

```
def fixBadZipfile(zipFile):  
     f = open(zipFile, 'r+b')  
     data = f.read()  
     pos = data.find('\x50\x4b\x05\x06') # End of central directory signature  
     if (pos > 0):  
         self._log("Truncating file at location " + str(pos + 22) + ".")  
         f.seek(pos + 22)   # size of 'ZIP end of central directory record' 
         f.truncate()  
         f.close()  
     else:  
         # raise error, file is truncated
```

Comment: I dont know if t his a Python version issue, but I got 
    TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
This is resolved by replacing everything in the parenthesis behind "data.find" with 
    b'\x50\x4b\x05\x06'

Comment: same @morph3us, did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You say using `less` on the file it shows such and such. Do you mean this?

```
less my_file
```

If so, I would guess these are comments that the zip program put in the
file. Looking at a user guide for the iSeries PKZIP I found on the web,
this appears to be the default behavior.

The docs for `zipfile` say "This module does not currently handle ZIP
files which have appended comments." Perhaps this is the problem? (Of
course, if `less` shows them, this would seem to imply that they're
*prepended*, FWIW.)

It appears you (or whoever created the zipfile on an iSeries machine)
can turn this off with `ARCHTEXT(*NONE)`, or use `ARCHTEXT(*CLEAR)` to
remove it from an existing zipfile.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Utilize mmap module to avoid a potential DoS exploit (e.g. by reading the
# whole zip file into memory). A bad zip file example can be found here:
# https://bugs.python.org/issue24621

import mmap
from io import UnsupportedOperation
from zipfile import BadZipfile

# The end of central directory signature
CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_SIGNATURE = b'\x50\x4b\x05\x06'


def repair_central_directory(zipFile):
    if hasattr(zipFile, 'read'):
        # This is a file-like object
        f = zipFile
        try:
            fileno = f.fileno()
        except UnsupportedOperation:
            # This is an io.BytesIO instance which lacks a backing file.
            fileno = None
    else:
        # Otherwise, open the file with binary mode
        f = open(zipFile, 'rb+')
        fileno = f.fileno()
    if fileno is None:
        # Without a fileno, we can only read and search the whole string
        # for the end of central directory signature.
        f.seek(0)
        pos = f.read().find(CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_SIGNATURE)
    else:
        # Instead of reading the entire file into memory, memory-mapped the
        # file, then search it for the end of central directory signature.
        # Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844624/2293304
        mm = mmap.mmap(fileno, 0)
        pos = mm.find(CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_SIGNATURE)
        mm.close()
    if pos > -1:
        # size of 'ZIP end of central directory record'
        f.truncate(pos + 22)
        f.seek(0)
        return f
    else:
        # Raise an error to make it fail fast
        raise BadZipfile('File is not a zip file')
```