# Find byte pair position in a binary file for editing with Python

Tags: python, binary, jpeg, edit

I have jpeg images stored in binary formats. In need to edit these binaries to delete all the byte pairs that come before `0xff 0xd8` (as this is the initial part of my jpegs).
The reason is that when I try to view these files in an image program, they won't open as long as I don't get rid of all the part of bytearray coming before this `0xff 0xd8` bytes.
Here's what I tried so far:

```
data= open ('C:/Users/Umberto/Desktop/_BR_Browse.001_2065642654_1.BINARY', 'rb+')
edit= str (data.read () )
data.close ()
edit.find ('/xff/xd8')
```

but I always receive '-1' as index, for whatever I put as argument using "find" method. What's wrong with the code?
Once I know the position of `/xff/xd8`, I would simply delete what comes before it somehow.

Comment: Use '\' instead of '/'

More information here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217334/python-searching-reading-binary-data

Comment: Look for `edit.find('\xff\xd8')` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with this line:

```
edit.find ('/xff/xd8')
```

Use '\' instead of '/'

```
edit.find ('\xff\xd8')
```

More information here:
[Python: Searching/reading binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217334/python-searching-reading-binary-data)

Answer (score 2):

Your escapes are the wrong way around. Try `edit.find('\xff\xd8')`