# python 'long' hex value to decimal

Tags: python

hi i want to hex value to decimal without loop(because 'speed' problem)

```
ex)
>>> myvalue = "\xff\x80\x17\x90\x12\x44\x55\x99\x90\x12\x80"
>>> int(myvalue)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xff\x80\x17\x90\x12DU\x99\x90\x12\x80'

>>> ord(myvalue)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 11 found
>>>
```

anyone helps ?

Comment: This does not look like a hex number.

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python

Comment: What do you want to get as output? List of character codes? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number seems to be an integer given as binary data.  In Python 3.2, you can convert it to a Python integer with `int.from_bytes()`:

```
>>> myvalue = b"\xff\x80\x17\x90\x12\x44\x55\x99\x90\x12\x80"
>>> int.from_bytes(myvalue, "big")
308880981568086674938794624
```

The best solution I can come up with for Python 2.x is

```
>>> myvalue = "\xff\x80\x17\x90\x12\x44\x55\x99\x90\x12\x80"
>>> int(myvalue.encode("hex"), 16)
308880981568086674938794624L
```

Since this does not involve a Python loop, it should be pretty fast, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a loop in there somewhere though :)

Comment: @wroniasty: That's why I wrote "no Python loop".

Comment: @wroniasty The loop would be written in C and not Python.

Comment: @jamylak Actually this depends on the Python implementation, it may as well be a Python loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` module will most likely not use a loop:

```
import struct
valuesTuple = struct.unpack ('L', myValue[:4])
```

Of course this limits the numerical values to basic data types (int, long int, etc.)

Comment: This method won't even work for the example given in the question, so I don't think it is a good answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach still it's the only one not involving a loop (probably) ;)