# copy 3 byte char to int

Tags: python, c, char, int

I have a byte stream with 3 bytes that I have to cast into an unsigned int 32. In C I would just use bzero to zero out the memory region of my integer and then copy the memory from the stream, something like

```
char* stream = ...;
Uint32 myInt;
bzero(myInt,4);
memcopy(myInt, stream[0], stream[3])
```

**Question:**

How would I do this in Python?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python

Comment: Not really, since I do no rely on the formats implemented in unpack (like L, H, ..)

Comment: `unpack` is not the only solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in C you should not use `memcpy` for binary de-serialization, because it doesn't deal with binary representation, i.e. endianess, sign and the like.  Explicitly decode binary values from a fixed representation in the stream to the platform's native representation.

In Python, you'd read the bytes from the stream, pad them according to the endianess, and then unpack them with `struct`:

```
chunk = fileobj.read(3)
# decode bytes as little-endian, signed integer
chunk += '\x00'
number = struct.unpack('<i', chunk)
```

`fileobj` is a file-like object, representing the opened stream, i.e. a file opened with `open(filename, 'rb')`.

Comment: The questioner's code with `memcpy` is fine for deserialising a network-order 32 bit unsigned integer from a stream. You deal with endianness *after* you read a value, that's what `ntohl` is for. Granted the same trick wouldn't work for a signed value if either end is non-2's-complement.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
myInt = (ord (myStr[0]) * 256 + ord (myStr[1])) * 256 + ord (myStr[2])
```

The following program:

```
myStr = "abc"
myInt = ord (myStr[0]) * 65536 + ord (myStr[1]) * 256 + ord (myStr[2])
print myInt
```

outputs `6382179` as expected:

```
'a' (97) * 65536 = 6356992
'b' (98) *   256 =   25088
'c' (99) *     1 =      99
                   -------
                   6382179
```

This is, of course, assuming the strings are in big-endian format. For little-endian, where the most significant octet is the *third* in the string, you can just reverse the string indexes (`2, 1, 0` rather than `0, 1, 2`).

Answer (score 0):

As @paxdiablo says, `ord` is the solution. Here is a solution with `<<` that makes it more familiar with C:

```
sum([ord(c) << 8 * i for i, c in enumerate(s) ])
```