# How can I print 4 bytes as an integer

Tags: python

I have an `array` of 4 `bytes` that I need to print it's value as an `Integer`. This is very easy in C, as I can cast and print with something like this:

```
 printf("Integer Value = %i", (int) pointer_to_4_bytes_array);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your C code doesn't do what you say it does. Even if you change it to cast to an `int *` and dereference the pointer, the result is going to be platform-specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a string of bytes into an int (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python2 (works on 3 too), you can use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html) module.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack(">L","1234")[0]
825373492
```

In Python3.2+, [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) does what you want. See @ryrich's answer

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b"1234",'big')
825373492
```

Comment: `struct` could be used on both Python 2 and 3 if you use `bytes` literal: `b'1234'`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)

**Note** : for Python 3.2

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer only applies to Python3.2 and newer.

Comment: thanks, made a note. For older versions, struct works.

Answer (score 1):

If your on Python 3.2+ there is a function:

```
int.from_bytes()
```

For python 2 you can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html).