# python convert bytearray to numbers in list

Tags: python, arrays

For the following `python` codes:

```
pt  = bytearray.fromhex('32 43 f6 a8 88 5a 30 8d 31 31 98 a2 e0 37 07 34')
state = bytearray(pt)
```

If I use:

```
print state
```

It gives out `2Cö¨ˆZ0?11˜¢à74`

Then how to recover the content in the `bytearray`? For example, to put them in a list like `[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259947/convert-variable-sized-byte-array-to-a-integer-long

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indexing a `bytearray` results in unsigned bytes.

```
>>> pt[0]
50
>>> pt[5]
90
```

Answer (score 16):

You can convert between a bytearray and list using the python 
built in functions of the same name.

```
>>> x=[0,1,2,3,4]      # create a list 
>>> print x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = bytearray(x)   # convert the list to a bytearray    
>>> print y
(garbled binary)               <-- prints UGLY!
>>> z = list(y)        # convert the bytearray back into a list
>>> print z
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own method with simple string methods:

```
string = '32 43 f6 a8 88 5a 30 8d 31 31 98 a2 e0 37 07 34'
number = [int(i, 16) for i in string.split()]
```

Now you have a list of the converted numbers as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to **'How may you convert binary into decimal values?'** and found this question, so I want to complete [Malik Brahimi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4338920/malik-brahimi) answer as much as I can.

Basically, what you can do is to create a list of ones and then iterate through them in order to create decimal list:

```
b_list = ['0', '1', '10', '11', '100', '101'] # Note, that values of list are strings
res = [int(n, 2) for n in b_list] # Convert from base two to base ten
print(res)

# Output:
# User@DESKTOP-CVQ282P MINGW64 ~/desktop
# $ python backpool.py
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You may note, that we can use this way to convert values with different bases: binary, hex and so on.