# How to encode a text string into a number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say you have a string:

```
mystring = "Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
```

I am looking for a way to convert that string into a number, like say:

```
encoded_string = number_encode(mystring)

print(encoded_string)

08713091353153848093820430298
```

..that you can convert back to the original string.

```
decoded_string = number_decode(encoded_string)

print(decoded_string)

"Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
```

It doesn't have to be cryptographically secure, but it does have to put out the same number for the same string regardless of what computer it's running on.

Comment: What do you want to do? To transmit the string over the network? If so, why don't use base 64 encoding, it's simple with `base64`.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to [encode the string as bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3) and then [decode those as an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259947/convert-variable-sized-byte-array-to-a-integer-long), then reverse the process to get the string back out. But it doesn't really make sense to do that IMO - are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Knowing why you want to do this would really help in coming up with the best way. @RandomDavis’s suggestion works for pretty much all strings (except for ones that start/end with `'\0'` characters depending on which you pick), but you can also get smaller numbers if your character set is more restricted. Or maybe you want fixed-size numbers. (Or to compress the string first?)

Comment: Depending on the output you want (one to one character mapping? Longer digit string than character string?) You can encode with `ord()` and decode with `chr()`, or you can replace according to a custom dict, or any number of options

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`encode` it to a `bytes` in a fixed encoding, then convert the `bytes` to an `int` with `int.from_bytes`. The reverse operation is to call `.to_bytes` on the resulting `int`, then  `decode` back to `str`:

```python
mystring = "Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
mybytes = mystring.encode('utf-8')
myint = int.from_bytes(mybytes, 'little')
print(myint)
recoveredbytes = myint.to_bytes((myint.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'little')
recoveredstring = recoveredbytes.decode('utf-8')
print(recoveredstring)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9LDoIwEED3nmJkQxsR4ieRjQdw7cKlgTJIk9KSMpD09LUKfjezeu/NTOeoMXrnfet6slLf4AjRBZUwLQIZoAbhpAntmQoLoqgxgR7t@CCdGaCXWiBs95vtMlq0rnSEfUi8ailqYSpk8UD1Oo95QKSmAISZ1ta016fBZjOBWEkihYHsgk/syfOFRWFGtFh9FjwKZGZ/4tJS0lWhvlHDOKzgwCHLIP@uvkPvb3/TaYW/B09n/Gnc@zs)

This has one flaw, which is that if the string ends in `NUL` characters (`'\0'`/`\x00'`) you'll lose them (switching to `'big'` byte order would lose them from the front). If that's a problem, you can always just pad with a `'\x01'` explicitly and remove it on the decode side so there are no trailing 0s to lose:

```python
mystring = "Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
mybytes = mystring.encode('utf-8') + b'\x01'  # Pad with 1 to preserve trailing zeroes
myint = int.from_bytes(mybytes, 'little')
print(myint)
recoveredbytes = myint.to_bytes((myint.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'little')
recoveredstring = recoveredbytes[:-1].decode('utf-8') # Strip pad before decoding
print(recoveredstring)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for making a certain string unreadable by a human you might use [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), `base64.b64encode(s, altchars=None)` and `base64.b64decode(s, altchars=None, validate=False)`:

Take into account that it requires bytes-like object, so you should start your strings with `b"I am a bytes-like string":`

```
>>> import base64
>>> coded = base64.b64encode(b"Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!")
>>> print(coded)
b'V2VsY29tZSB0byB0aGUgSW50ZXJTdGFyIGNhZmUsIHNlcnZpbmcgeW91IHNpbmNlIDI0MTIh'
>>> print(base64.b64decode(coded))
b"Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
```

If you already have your strings, you can convert them with `str.encode('utf-8')`:

```
>>> myString = "Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!"
>>> bString = myString.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(bString)
b'Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!'
>>> print(bString.decode())
'Welcome to the InterStar cafe, serving you since 2412!'
```

If you really need to convert the string to only numbers, you would have to use [@ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55407783/7655838).

Comment: You're assuming "encoding" is the only goal. They may have some API that requires a true integer (some toy RSA encrypter or the like), and this won't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are better than this one, but purely mathematically, there is an obvious way of doing this. You just have to interpret a message as an integer written in another base system with different symbols

```py
def frombase(s, sym):
    b = len(sym)
    n = 0
    bl = 1
    for a in reversed(s):
        n += sym.index(a) * bl
        bl *= b
    return n

def tobase(n, sym):
    b = len(sym)
    s = ''
    while n > 0:
        kl = n % b
        n //= b
        s += sym[kl]
    return s[::-1] if s else sym[0]
```

and then for your specific case

```py
symbols = [
    ' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
    'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
    'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
    'Y', 'Z', ',', '.', '?', '!', '-', ':', ';',
    '_', '"', "'", '#', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')',
    '=', '+', '*', '<', '>', '~'
]
encodeword = lambda w: frombase(w, symbols)
decodeword = lambda n: tobase(n, symbols)
```

Though the first symbol (" ") will be omitted if there's nothing in front of it, similarly to 0001 = 1.

If you really want to represent all possible symbols, you can write them as a sequence of their `ord` values (integers), seperated by the `,` symbol. Then you encode that in the base with an added `,` symbol:

```py
symbols = [',', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] # , is zero
txt2int = lambda w: encodeword(','.join(str(ord(x)) for x in w))
int2txt = lambda n: ''.join(chr(int(x)) for x in decodeword(n).split(','))
```

Regarding the size of the returned integer: `txt2int(w) = encodeword(w) = O(len(w))`, meaning e.g. 'Hi there!' would encode to a number with about 9 digits.

Comment: I like your answer, but what does the variable name `bl` stand for?

Comment: @scribe  `l` is an index of `b`. It made sense in the context of an article I was writing https://medium.com/p/34d8ffd498fb