# Prepending bytearray: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have two `bytearray`s:

```
ba1 = bytearray(b'abcdefg')
ba2 = bytearray(b'X')
```

How can I insert ("prepend") `ba2` in `ba1`?

I tried to do:

```
ba1.insert(0, ba2)
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct.

Of course I could do following:

```
ba2.extend(ba1)
ba1 = ba2
```

But what if `ba1` is very big?
Would this mean unnecessary coping of the whole `ba1`?
Is this memory-efficient?

How can I prepend a `bytearray`?

Comment: Have you read this? http://dabeaz.blogspot.se/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html

Comment: What is the problem with `ba2 + ba1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a string of bytes into an int (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python)

Comment: Since you want to insert stuff at the start of ba1 you can't really get around the need to copy its current contents. OTOH, adding stuff at the end of a bytearray isn't particularly efficient, either: it's similar to concatenating to a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
ba1 = bytearray(b'abcdefg')
ba2 = bytearray(b'X')

ba1 = ba2 + ba1
print(ba1)  # --> bytearray(b'Xabcdefg')
```

To make it more obvious that an insert at the beginning is being done, you could use this instead:

```
ba1[:0] = ba2  # Inserts ba2 into beginning of ba1.
```

Also note that as a special case where you know `ba2` is only one byte long, this would work:

```
ba1.insert(0, ba2[0])  # Valid only if len(ba2) == 1
```

Comment: @Downvoter: What's wrong with this answer? +1 Since this works for me.