# Reading 4 bytes of data as a Long with Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, arrays, long-integer

I have four bytes which I need to read as a `long`.

When I read my file, I read the following bytes:

```
['\x10', '\xef', '\xf1', '\xea']
```

According to my file format description, these four bytes represent a long.

How would I convert these bytes to a long with Python?

Additionally: Would one use a similar method to convert 2 bytes into a Short?

Here is example code of how I read my file:

```
source = "test.whatever"
print "Loading file:", source;
data = []   
f = open(source, "rb")
counter = 0;

#Let's load the data here:
try:
    byte = f.read(1) #skip the first byte according to my file
    while byte != "": 
        byte = f.read(1)
        data.append(byte)  #read every byte into an array to work on later
        counter = counter + 1

finally:
    f.close()
print "File loaded."
print counter
```

Comment: See if your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python   (talks about ints, but should apply). BTW `long` in Python is more like BigInt in Java, not like long.

Comment: Thanks Ray- I'll check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import struct
struct.unpack('>l', ''.join(ss))
```

I chose to [interpret](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) it as big-endian, you need to decide that yourself and use `<` instead if your data is little-endian.

If possible, use `unpack_from()` to read the data directly from your file, instead of using an intermediate list-of-single-char-strings.

Comment: So maybe this is something to discuss as well: How the data is being read. I'll update my question with some example code.

Comment: @FredFury: right, so you should stop reading one byte at a time, and instead read the largest chunks you can.  And further, you can use `unpack_from()` to do the actual reading and avoid storing strings of data only to convert them to structs.

Comment: So I've been looking into this. The advantage of using an array is that you can index the bytes, which helps when you need to read a set of bytes at a location. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Well you can read the whole file into a string if you need to, just do it at once instead of one byte at a time into a list.  A string can be indexed.