# Unable convert to int from bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the next value

```
value = bytearray(b'\x85\x13\xbd|\xfb\xbc\xc3\x95\xbeL6L\xfa\xbf0U_`$]\xca\xee]z\xef\xa0\xd6(\x15\x8b\xca\x0e\x1f7\xa9\xf0\xa4\x98\xc5\xdf\xcdM5\xef\xc2\x052`\xeb\x13\xd9\x99B.\x95\xb2\xbd\x96\xd9\x14\xe6F\x9e\xfd\xd8\x00')
```

when I try to convert in python3.x it works well.

```
>>> int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='little')
2909369579440607969688280064437289348250138784421305732473112318543540722321676649649580720015118044118243611774710427666475769804427735898727217762490192773
```

How to convert it in python2.7? I already read the [convert a string of bytes into an int (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python)

```
struct.unpack(fmt, value)[0]
```

But don't know what to do with fmt.

Comment: You just want one great big number out form that?

Comment: Yes I want. I can't imagine what I need to put to fmt. Is this length of the value?

Comment: `struct.unpack` isn't appropriate for your case, you have too many bytes. You want http://stackoverflow.com/a/444814/8747

Comment: @Robᵩ: Almost, we need to reverse `value` to get the same number as in the OP. Eg, `int(str(value[::-1]).encode('hex'), 16)`. Or `sum(v << (8 * i) for i,v in enumerate(value))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just write your own `from_bytes` function in Python 2:

```
def from_bytes (data, big_endian = False):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        data = bytearray(data)
    if big_endian:
        data = reversed(data)
    num = 0
    for offset, byte in enumerate(data):
        num += byte << (offset * 8)
    return num
```

Used like this:

```
>>> data = b'\x85\x13\xbd|\xfb\xbc\xc3\x95\xbeL6L\xfa\xbf0U_`$]\xca\xee]z\xef\xa0\xd6(\x15\x8b\xca\x0e\x1f7\xa9\xf0\xa4\x98\xc5\xdf\xcdM5\xef\xc2\x052`\xeb\x13\xd9\x99B.\x95\xb2\xbd\x96\xd9\x14\xe6F\x9e\xfd\xd8\x00'
>>> from_bytes(data)
2909369579440607969688280064437289348250138784421305732473112318543540722321676649649580720015118044118243611774710427666475769804427735898727217762490192773L
```

As for `struct`, you cannot really use this, as it only supports unpacking elements of a [certain kind](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), up to 8 byte integers. But since you want to handle arbitrary byte strings, you will have to use something else.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `.encode('hex')` and `int(x, 16)`:

```
num = int(str(value).encode('hex'), 16)
```

Note that you need to use something like

```
int(''.join(reversed(value)).encode('hex'), 16)
```

in order to parse it as *little* endian.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/444814/8747

Comment: Note that you need to use something like `int(''.join(reversed(value)).encode('hex'), 16)` in order to parse it as *little* endian.

Comment: After benchmarking, I found out that this is ridiculously faster than my solution although this is parsing a string… Good find!

Comment: You can use `str(value[::-1])` instead of `''.join(reversed(value))` for little endian, not sure if there's any advantage to one over the other.