# Convert data received from a socket.recv (bytes) to a boolean value in ironpython

Tags: python, sockets, struct, casting, ironpython

I am using a python script as a TCP client.  At one point it receives what should be a bool back from the server.  When I was first writing this and testing it on a machine that was using a regular python install I was able to use the following code from the struct module to unpack the data received back as a bool

```
data = socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
result = struct.unpack("?", data)[0]
if not result:
    #do stuff here
```

I currently need to perform the same task in an environment that only uses ironpython.  When I attempt to run the code I get the following:

```
ImportError: No module named struct
```

After a bit of digging it seems that the struct module in regular python doesn't exist in ironpython (I believe a struct module exists, but it is for interfacing with c/c++ structs)

How can I take the data from a TCP socket.recv and convert it from the bytes format actually received to the bool type I need it to be in ironpython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python) which was asking about converting a string of bytes to an int.

I found the solution offered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444814/5220640) avoided having to import any modules and worked quite well, I needed to perform an additional conversion to bool so my final result looks like this:

```
data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
result = bool(int(data.encode('hex'), 16))
```