# Convert 16 bytes of random data to integer in Python

Tags: python, string, random, binary, int

I have generated a random 16 byte string. It looks like this:

```
b'\xb68 \xe9L\xbd\x97\xe0\xd6Q\x91c\t\xc3z\\'
```

I want to convert this to a (positive) integer. What's the best way to do this in Python?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What's its intended endianness?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python

Comment: @Logan I saw that post too, but I don't understand why to use struct? That can't be the solution.

Comment: @kindall Little Endian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3.2+, you can use `int.from_bytes()`:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xb68 \xe9L\xbd\x97\xe0\xd6Q\x91c\t\xc3z\\', byteorder='little')
122926391642694380673571917327050487990
```

You can also use 'big' byteorder:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xb68 \xe9L\xbd\x97\xe0\xd6Q\x91c\t\xc3z\\', byteorder='big')
242210931377951886843917078789492013660
```

You can also specify if you want to use two's complement representation. For more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Oh I think that's exactly what I need. If my data is random, I think it does not matter if I use little or big endian, it will just shuffle the number, right?

Comment: I guess it would depend on what exactly you're planning on doing with the integer, but yes, the number will be different if you change the byteorder.

Comment: What is the command to go back to the original string from that number?

Comment: Looks like you could use int.to_bytes(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Answer (score 2):

A solution compatible both with Python 2 and Python 3 is to use struct.unpack:

```
import struct
n = b'\xb68 \xe9L\xbd\x97\xe0\xd6Q\x91c\t\xc3z\\'
m = struct.unpack("<QQ", n)
res = (m[0] << 64) | m[1]
print(res)
```

Result: 298534947350364316483256053893818307030L