# convert list of bytes to int32 in python3

Tags: python, list, binary, int32

i have a list of several 4x6 bytes (32bit) values in byte format. Is there any possibility to convert these binary values efficient in 32bit integers in python?

There is the method int.from_bytes(xTest, byteorder='little', signed = True), but it would be very inefficient to loop through all the values. Maybe someone have an idea?

xTest = [b'\xf8\x80[\xf0', b'\x12\x81\x87\xef', b'-\x81\xc0\xee', b'I\x81\xf9\xed']

Comment: perhaps you can use `map()`

Comment: join the list to one string and use `struct` or `numpy`.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that `int.from_bytes()` is inefficient. According to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python it outperforms `struct.unpack`. Change your call to `int.from_bytes(b''.join(xTest), byteorder='little', signed = True)`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if i use the int.from_bytes() in this way i would get one number of the whole list. But i want to get 4 32bit integers. So i would need to loop through it or is there another possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension to apply the same operator to each of the element of your original `xTest` list:

```
int_list = [int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='little', signed = True) for x in xTest]
```

Here `x` loops through  each of the element (thus, your 4 bytes) of `xTest` and thus allows you to apply the same operator to each of them.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I only wonder about, if i set x to 1 or 4 i get the same result.