# Read int values stored in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, file-handling, public-key-encryption

I am writing a program to encrypt a file using RSA algo in python without using Crypto library. i have generated the keys and the e, n and d are stored in a .pem file. Now in another strict where the encrypting is taking place i am using the e, d and n values, but every time i am running the script an error is showing :

```
 File "rsaencrypt.py", line 91, in <module>
 main()
 File "rsaencrypt.py", line 62, in main
 encrypt = pow(content, e, n)      
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'bytes','_io.TextIOWrapper', '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

heres how i am opening the file in the encryption script and using pow() to encrypt the files:

```
    n = open('nfile.pem', 'r')
    c = open('cfile.pem', 'r')
    d = open('dfile.pem', 'r'))
    encrypt = pow(content, e, n)
```

I have searched the internet for how to read the int value from a file but i have found nothing.

Heres how i am saving the values in efile, dfile, and nfile:

```
#saving the values of n, d and e for further use    
efile = open('efile.pem', 'w')
efile.write('%d' %(int(e)))
efile.close()

dfile = open('dfile.pem', 'w')
dfile.write('%d' %(int(d)))
dfile.close()

nfile = open('nfile.pem', 'w')
nfile.write('%d' % (int(n)))
nfile.close()
```

the values are stored like this: 564651648965132684135419864..............454

Now as want to encrypt the files i need to read the integer values written in the efile, dfile and nfile to use the values in the pow() as arguments.

Looking forward to suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried casting the read value to an int? Like you do when writing to the file `int(value)`

Comment: yes i did like this n=int(open('filename', 'r')) , but then another error is showing 
  
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open()` function returns a file object, not the int. You need to convert returned object into `int` value by:

```
n = open('nfile.pem', 'r')
n_value = int(list(n)[0])
```

etc.

Another option (same result) is:

```
n = open('nfile.pem', 'r')
n_value = int(n.read())
```

Comment: its showing an error in the pow() like : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'bytes', 'int', 'int'

Comment: as i am using the values as args to pow() i need the contents in integer form that are written in the file

Comment: That's correct :) This answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python

Comment: oh thank you, how can i miss it. The error is in the ''contents" not in the e or n

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use `with`, this ensures your file is closed once you are done with it rather than waiting for garbage collection or explicitly calling `f.close()` to close your file.

```
n_results = []

with open('nfile.pem', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do something
        try:
            n.append(int(i))
        except TypeError:
            n.append(0) #you can replace 0 with any value to indicate a processing error
```

Also, utilize `try-except` block in case you have noise in your file that cannot be converted to integers. `n_results` return a list of all your values from your files which you can use to aggregate or combine them later for a single output.

This would be a better foundation as your project scales and if you deal with more data.