# How to convert bytes string to integer values?

Tags: python

I am working on a project in which i send a base64 encoded image from my app to a server where the processing happens. The image received on the server is like this:
(this data is huge)

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1\x02;Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\.....'
```

So, now i want to convert it in this format:
[255, 234, 70, 115, ....].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string of bytes into an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/how-to-convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int)

Comment: Did you try `list(img_data)`? Depending on your definition of "huge" (i.e. if it actually doesn't fit in memory) you may want to do `for c in iter(img_data)` instead.

Comment: @JordanDimov Yes, didn't know it would be that simple :), Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw the list constructor at it.

```
>>> list(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1')
[255, 216, 255, 225]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Python3, iterating over the byte string actually gives you individual values as an int type:

```py
>>> s = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1\x02'
>>> for c in s:
...     print(c, type(c))
... 
255 <class 'int'>
216 <class 'int'>
255 <class 'int'>
225 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
```