# Generate a random floating point, with no range constraint, but including +inf, -inf, NaN, in python

Tags: python, random

Python's random number generator allows us to generate a floating point in some range. I wonder how can we generate a floating point number without the range constraint. The random floating point number I want to generate can be NaN, +inf, -inf, or any number in between the minimal and maximal floating point number.

I am looking for a pythonic solution. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn’t really make sense. What should the odds of `nan` appearing be?

Comment: @minitech What do you mean? NaN can be encoded into FP, anyway.

Comment: I know. Does that mean you want to generate random bytes and treat them as a floating-point number? It won’t give you a uniform distribution.

Comment: It's also worth noting that randomly choosing 8 bytes and interpreting them as a float will make the various NaNs more likely than other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excellent testing library [hypothesis](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) may suit your needs if you are generating the numbers as part of a test suite.  This will not answer your case of a "random" float, but I believe that is impossible anyway if including `nan` and `inf` numbers. What it will do is generate a bunch of float values in an attempt to cover edge cases.

```
>>> from hypothesis.strategies import floats
>>> get_float = floats().example

>>> get_float
WrapperFloatStrategy(GaussianFloatStrategy() | BoundedFloatStrategy() 
   | ExponentialFloatStrategy() | JustIntFloats() |
   SampledFromStrategy((0.0, 2.2250738585072014e-308, 
   -2.2250738585072014e-308, -1.7976931348623157e+308,    
   1.7976931348623157e+308, inf, -inf, nan)) | FullRangeFloats())

>>> get_float()
-1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> get_float()
inf
>>> get_float()
49215.0
```

As you can see, it will generate a random-ish number fitting the properties of a float, including `inf`, `-inf`, and `nan`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that is to generate some random integers/bytes and convert them to float using [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).  Since a quite a few byte combinations are actually not valid floating point numbers you will get a lot of NaNs.  INFs are bit trickier you will only get them if your random bytes combination happens to be just right. Look here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python) for more details.

Comment: Can you clarify how you get `nan, inf, -inf` from this method?

Comment: This ends up with a pretty bad distribution for most purposes IME. Almost every finite float generated will be either very small or very large. It also very rarely generates nan or inf.

Answer (score 3):

Standard pseudo-random number generators which return values in a range [a,b] are simulations of uniform random variables on [a,b] -- something which has a clear mathematical model. There simply doesn't exist any uniform distribution on [-infinity, +infinity], so it isn't clear what you are trying to simulate. In any reasonable interpretation of what you are trying to do, +inf and -inf would be vanishingly rare -- so why even bother? You could somewhat arbitrarily decide that you want -inf, +inf to occur a certain percentage of the time (say 1 in a million) and write a function which return -inf on average 1 in a million time, + inf 1 in a million times, and the remaining times return a randomly chosen number in a large range of floats. Something like:

```
def extendedRandom(a,b,infProb):
    myRoll = random.random()
    if myRoll < infProb:
        return float('-inf')
    elif myRoll < 2*infProb:
        return float('+inf')
    else:
        return random.uniform(a,b)
```

Used like thus:

```
>>> for i in range(20):
    print(extendedRandom(-10**15,10**15,0.2))

-inf
inf
339184853623024.5
936746547842162.5
211578440289046.5
inf
-654872390518085.2
524487814975436.5
250131763600250.75
-inf
-880823611470973.4
inf
354024482521076.75
-369458678524420.25
inf
-537391531707519.94
-inf
-298740652509172.0
-inf
-inf
```

Ad hoc -- but if you want a random number generator which throws out a + or - inf at times then this would work.