# STL binary file reader with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write my "personal" python version of STL binary file reader, according to WIKIPEDIA : A binary STL file contains :

- an 80-character (byte) headern which is generally ignored.
- a 4-byte unsigned integer indicating the number of triangular facets in the file.
- Each triangle is described by twelve 32-bit floating-point numbers: three for the normal and then three for the X/Y/Z coordinate of each vertex – just as with the ASCII version of STL. After these follows a 2-byte ("short") unsigned integer that is the "attribute byte count" – in the standard format, this should be zero because most software does not understand anything else. --Floating-point numbers are represented as IEEE floating-point numbers and are assumed to be little-endian--

Here is my code :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

with open("stlbinaryfile.stl","rb") as fichier :

head=fichier.read(80) 
nbtriangles=fichier.read(4)
print(nbtriangles)
```

The output is :

```
b'\x90\x08\x00\x00'
```

It represents an unsigned integer, I need to convert it without using any package (struct,stl...). Are there any (basic) rules to do it ?, I don't know what does \x mean ? How does \x90 represent one byte ?

most of the answers in google mention "C structs", but I don't know nothing about C.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why the restriction on using `import struct`?

Comment: It should be original. I have to start from zero. with only basic functions.

Comment: I would argue that `struct.unpack` *is* a "basic function." More to the point, it is part of the standard library, available in every Python installation.

Comment: But if I use it the project I work on will have no meaning, th purpose is to create STL binary file reader, without using : struct.unpack ,int.from_bytes..., All that I need is how (the rules) to convert \x##\x##...... knowing the type.

Comment: Okay, if you can't use `struct.unpack` nor `int.from_bytes`, consider the second alternative in my answer.

Comment: Also, putting together the floating-point values by hand will be way harder than putting together the integers.

Comment: you're right, but I have to do it, do you know how ? or just tell me where can I learn about this

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python https://gist.github.com/kg/2192799  Note that you'll probably never find Python sample code to do this, since `struct.unpack`  the Python way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to interpret an integer is to use `struct.unpack`, like so:

```
import struct

with open("stlbinaryfile.stl","rb") as fichier :
    head=fichier.read(80)
    nbtriangles=fichier.read(4)
    print(nbtriangles)
    nbtriangles=struct.unpack("<I", nbtriangles)
    print(nbtriangles)
```

If you are allergic to `import struct`, then you can also compute it by hand:

```
def unsigned_int(s):
    result = 0
    for ch in s[::-1]:
        result *= 256
        result += ch
    return result

...
nbtriangles = unsigned_int(nbtriangles)
```

---

As to what you are seeing when you print `b'\x90\x08\x00\x00'`. You are printing a `bytes` object, which is an array of integers in the range [0-255]. The first integer has the value 144 (decimal) or 90 (hexadecimal). When printing a `bytes` object, that value is represented by the string `\x90`. The 2nd has the value eight, represented by `\x08`. The 3rd and final integers are both zero. They are presented by `\x00`.

If you would like to see a more familiar representation of the integers, try:

```
print(list(nbtriangles))

[144, 8, 0, 0]
```

To compute the 32-bit integers represented by these four 8-bit integers, you can use this formula:

```
total = byte0 + (byte1*256) + (byte2*256*256) + (byte3*256*256*256)
```

Or, in hex:

```
total = byte0 + (byte1*0x100) + (byte2*0x10000) + (byte3*0x1000000)
```

Which results in:

```
0x00000890
```

Perhaps you can see the similarities to decimal, where the string "1234" represents the number:

```
4 + 3*10 + 2*100 + 1*1000
```

Comment: That's what I am talking about, but unsigned_int() converts b'*\x1c\x02\x00' (another example) to 138282,  * represents 48 , I don't know why ?, know I have to interpret the rest of the file (see my answer 3rd item in the list  ...

Comment: , for the first point the 50-bytes are : ( b'\x9a'
b'\xa3'
b'\x14'
b'\xbe'
b'\x05'
b'$'
b'\x85'
b'\xbe'
b'N'
b'b'
b't'
b'?'
b'\xcd'
b'\xa6'
b'\x04'
b'\xc4'
b'\xfb'
b';'
b'\xd4'
b'\xc1'
b'\x84'
b'w'
b'\x81'
b'A'
b'\xcd'
b'\xa6'
b'\x04'
b'\xc4'
b'\xa5'
b'\x15'
b'\xd3'
b'\xc1'
b'\xb2'
b'\xc7'
b'\x81'
b'A'
b'\xef'
b'\xa6'
b'\x04'
b'\xc4'
b'\x81'
b'\x14'
b'\xd3'
b'\xc1'
b'Y'
b'\xc7'
b'\x81'
b'A'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
)
How can I convert this by hand ( some bytes don't start with \x )
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want to see the decimal equivalents of the integers in the byte array, print them as a list: `list(b'*\x1c\x02\x00') == [42, 28, 2, 0]`. If you want to convert that by hand, don't `print (nbtriangles)`. Instead `print(list(nbtriangles))` or `for digit in nbtriangles: print(digit)`

Comment: yes,yes,yes , but I really don't know how to convert it if it reprsents a floating point,

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Python 3, you can [use `int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes). I'm guessing the value is stored little-endian, so you'd just do:

```
 nbtriangles = int.from_bytes(fichier.read(4), 'little')
```

Change the second argument to `'big'` if it's supposed to be big-endian.

Mind you, the normal way to parse a fixed width type is the `struct` module, but apparently you've ruled that out.

For the confusion over the `repr`, `bytes` objects will display ASCII printable characters (e.g. `a`) or standard ASCII escapes (e.g. `\t`) if the byte value corresponds to one of them. If it doesn't, it uses `\x##`, where `##` is the hexadecimal representation of the byte value, so `\x90` represents the byte with value 0x90, or 144. You need to combine the byte values at offsets to reconstruct the `int`, but `int.from_bytes` does this for you faster than any hand-rolled solution could.

**Update:** Since apparent `int.from_bytes` isn't "basic" enough, a couple more complex, but only using top-level built-ins (not alternate constructors) solutions. For little-endian, you can do this:

```
def int_from_bytes(inbytes):
    res = 0
    for i, b in enumerate(inbytes):
        res |= b << (i * 8)  # Adjust each byte individually by 8 times position
    return res
```

You can use the same solution for big-endian by adding `reversed` to the loop, making it `enumerate(reversed(inbytes))`, or you can use this alternative solution that handles the offset adjustment a different way:

```
def int_from_bytes(inbytes):
    res = 0
    for b in inbytes:
        res <<= 8  # Adjust bytes seen so far to make room for new byte
        res |= b   # Mask in new byte
    return res
```

Again, this big-endian solution can trivially work for little-endian by looping over `reversed(inbytes)` instead of `inbytes`. In both cases `inbytes[::-1]` is an alternative to `reversed(inbytes)` (the former makes a new `bytes` in reversed order and iterates that, the latter iterates the existing bytes object in reverse, but unless it's a huge `bytes` object, enough to strain RAM if you copy it, the difference is pretty minimal).

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger for your help,
I know it sounds strange, but I should use basic functions only, so I have to discover how to convert (the rules) to create my own "int.from_bytes",For example to convert manually  b'\x90\x08\x00\x00' (which I know to be an unsigned integer) what should I do ? : 144+8+0+0=152 ?? I didn't get the meaning of OFFSET, where can I found it ?

I have also to convert some 32-bit floating-point numbers from \x## format ( I have edited my answer - 3rd list's item)

Comment: @Pylint424: `int.from_bytes` is a "basic" function (it's exactly as basic as `int` itself), so it would help if you define "basic" so I know what's available. Regardless, the offset is about shifting the bits; assuming little endian, the first byte requires no shifting before combining, the second requires a shift of 8, the third a shift of 16, etc. `144 + (8 << 8) == 2192`. Converting binary representation of a floating point value without assistance from `struct` module is much more annoying, I have no idea what sort of assignment would encourage you to do that in Python.

Comment: @Pylint424: I added alternatives to `int.from_bytes`. For floating point, I'd suggest asking a new question; floating point is a totally different animal, and it wasn't part of your original question at all.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, now I have 3 methods to do the conversion, I still have a small problem : int_from_bytes(b'*\x1c\x02\x00') returns 138282 ==> * is interpreted as 48 ?? thanks for your time, I'll ask another question .

Comment: @Pylint424: Read the original part of my answer. The `repr` of `bytes` will use the character corresponding to the ASCII value of that byte if the byte is printable ASCII, for brevity (it's one character in the `repr` instead of four for an escape). If you check a table of ASCII values, you'll see that `*` has an ordinal of 42 (I have no idea where you got 48, it's not 48).

Comment: Ok I get it thanks you, just give an example of FOUR characters escape, yes I made a mistake it's 42, the problem now is floating point : you know where can I learn about it ?