# How to receive float values using python sockets which are sent from posix sockets?

Tags: c, python-3.x, sockets, posix, ipc

I am trying to send an array of 8 floats using POSIX sockets in C and receiving them through sockets created using Python program. But the python socket on the other side is receiving it as a byte format. I am unable to convert it to float. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You send it as bytes and recieve as bytes.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python