# Bytes with non-ascii characters to string python

Tags: python, json, python-3.6, decode

I've got json string, and I need to load it but it comes from TCP socket so it is in bytes. Normal decoding with utf-8 doesn't work, because in thah string there are float numbers in 4bytes format.

```
data = b'{"X1":"Cf\x19\x9a","X2":"\x00\x00\x00\x00"}'
```

how to load this into json.loads?

Comment: That's not valid json, so you can't parse it with `json.load`.

Comment: I know that this is not valid json, but how to decode it, and not lose any data, even zeros?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, because it does not contain data encoded with UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 codecs.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now

Comment: The `\xhh` byte points are just representations of the actual byte values; your data does not contain literal `\` and `x` bytes, each `\xHH` sequence is *one byte*. But the hex sequence 19 9A is not a valiid UTF-8 byte sequence, so this can't be parsed as JSON *just for that reason*.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415/2988730?

Comment: Is the data all in this relatively flat format, or do you get more complicated nested structures sometimes?

Comment: Only flat format, I need to convert the hole data to string, and when there is a non-ascii char just put the hexstring of it.

Comment: Maybe better question would be: how to deal with non ascii chars in json.