# struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Tags: python-3.x, struct

I want to convert data from a device from bites to float
I use the code from this answer

[bytes to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers-in-python)

```
import struct

byte_file = b'+001.80\r'
print(type(byte_file))

y = struct.unpack('f' , byte_file)
print(y)
```

I get this `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`

The correct outcome should be `1.80`
do I need to implement a buffer argument ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`struct` is used for *binary packed data* - data that is not human-readable. `b'+001.80\r'` is 8 bytes long: `b'+', b'0', b'0', b'1', b'.', ...`.

You can just `decode` it and use `float`:

```
>>> b'+001.80\r'.decode()
'+001.80\r'
>>> float(_)
1.8
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('f', _)
b'ff\xe6?'  # doesn't look anything like your data!
```

*However*, because your data is 8 bytes long, you could treat it as a single `double`-precision floating-point value:

```
>>> struct.unpack('d', b'+001.80\r')
(3.711588247816385e-245,)
```

But that treats the data as binary-packed: `+001.80\r`, also known as `2b 30 30 31 2e 38 30 0d`, is what `3.711588247816385e-245` looks like in memory.