# How to read a binary file in python and convert it into an array of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I read a binary file (which I took from [http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/oxbuildings/](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/oxbuildings/)) in Python which contains the SIFT descriptor vectors of images, thus I want to turn my data to an array of integer or float numbers. I use the following pieces of code:

```
go_to_streaming = generator("data.bin")
for i in range(10):
    print(go_to_streaming.__next__())

def generator(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as entry:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: entry.read(64 * 8), b''):  # (64 * 8) is the size of chunks and needs to change.
            yield chunk
```

I read the file by chunks of (64 * 8) bits (correct me if I'm wrong) with each iteration. Now, I get the following results for the first 10 iterations:

```
b'&\x12\x04\x01\x04\x06\x05\x01S*\x11\x05\x03\x01\x00\x04\x01!3+\x0c\x00\x00\x00N\x04\n0\x13\x01\x00\r[2\x10\x0b\n\x03\x00\rwN$\x16\x01\x00\x00\x0e:NKN>\x00\x00\x01u\x00\x049w\x05\x00\x1a\\?\x02\x04\x04\x04\x15\x1bw"\x0f\x12\x00\x05LCR\x16\x04&ICw2H\x00\x00\x14wP\x1a\x1e\r\x06\x00\x00\x00\x048\x19\x07\x01\x01\x01\x01\x0ew\'\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03$w\x17\x04\x01\x01\x00\x0c-1\nn2\x04\x01\x00\x00\x01\x0fD$.4\x01\n9\x1d\x00\x00%1\x02\nj*\x01\x01\n\x0b\x02\x01WD\x7f%\x02\x01\x00\x00\x01\x06\x7f"0>\r\x12\x10\x05\x00\x00&]W#\x08\x01\x00\x00\x05\x1b7\x14\x19\x11\x7f\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x01\x03\x19}\x06\x00\x031T&\x11\x00\x00\x00\x024\x7fM\x04\x00\x00\x00\n,"$\x0eI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1dN\x1b\x00\x00\x07\x1f<\x7fJ\x00\x00\x00\x0e4`J\n\x00\x00\x00\x03\x02\x04,+f\x1c\x01\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00U\'\x18F\x0b\x00\x00\x0b\x0b\t\x19\x1b\x01\x03\x1e2\x04)\x15\x02\x08\x11\x12\x03\x7f\x1f\x01\x02\n\x01\x00\x07\x7f,&o\r\x04\x00\x05\x1f Cp\x18\x06\x0b\x0c\x1dV-\x05\x06\n\x06\x06\x7f\x03\x00\x01\x05\x02\x03:\x7f\x02\x02\x11\n\x18\\_\x16\x0c\x10=\x0e\x1er\r\x13\x0b\x08\x05\x0cFZ\t\x1c\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06&\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x7f[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x7f\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002n\x02h\x1a\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x1c=3\x0f\x11\x05\r\x13\x1d D$$\n\x05\x06\x01\x00\x03\'"\n\x05\x08\x01\x84\x18\x03\x00\x00\x01\x04\x07\x84=\x19\x17\x06\x00\x01\x07=2\r\x1f\x11\n\x0c\x16\x02\x0e\x1aB\x17\x0f(\x04\x84\x11\x01\x00\x00\x01\x03\x12\x84\x17\x06\x05\x05@\x17\x1a\x14\t\x03\x07\x05\x84\x84\x0b\x01\x04\x06\x05\x01h\x84\x11q\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\r(?\x02\x01\x00\x04\x84J\'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x848\x03\x02\x03\x04\x02\x03\x18\x1a\x06'
b'/\x1c\x04\x1bN\t\x00\x02tT\x16\x11\x0b\x02\x05\x12\x02\x05\x1f,F\x0c\x0b\r)\x06\x08\x11\x14\x03\x05\x14q$\x02\x0cX2\n\ttB\x07\x0c\x06\x04\x08\x1f\x16\x0b\x08Vt\x01\x02\tD\x05\x00\x124\x02\x02\'nE\x06\t\x1c"\t\x19tD\t\n\x08\x07\x141J\x0b\x03Vt\x04\x05$@\x03\x00\x1eL\x03\x02$^\n\x00\x00\x01\x14\x1a.j\x13\x03\x04\x06\x156d*\x07\x02&^\x06\x074\x1e\x02\x00"M\x01\x01\x12>\x1e\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b+kj\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06!P \x03\x03\x00\x00\t\r\x07\x03\t\x19\x05\x00\x00\x82\x11\x00\x01\x00\x00\x002\x82F\x15\x02\x01\x00\x00\x10\x06\x13\x12\x07\x14\x1b\x06\x07:\x15\x01\x01\'+\x03\x02\x82\x13\x03\x1c\t\x01\x00-\x82=\x03\x04\x08\x0e#B\x04\x03\x02\x074y#\x05X\x11\x00\x00\x0b:\x15\x17 \x00\x00\t\x0f\x11\x0bH\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x82\x82\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06g\x82\n\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x824\x13#\x18\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07"\x81-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x81=\x00\x00\x00\x01,\t8\x14\x00\x00\x00\t\x814\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x81Lv?\x06\x00\x00\t\x00\n\x81e\x05\x00\x00\x00\n\x15\x81=\x01\x02\x02\x02\x81\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x81\x17\x02\t\x07\x00\x01 \x02\x08\x13\x14\x10\x07\x00\x02\x00\x02\x0c\x05\x1a^\x1b\x00\x81\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00+r$\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x01\x06\n\t0\x0b\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05oX\x04\x00C>\x1d\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01=5yt\x00\x00\x00\x05\x02Syg\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08O*\x10\x0b\x01\x00\x00y*\n+\x05\x00\x00\ny;$\'\x13\x04\x04 \x0f\x17iiL\x16\x18\x0e\x0f\x10\x0e\x15Q\x15\x00\x02\\/\x15/\x04\x00\x00$y&\x13\x08\x0e\n\x08[\x0c\x03\x08\x10WZ\x0b\x15\x18\t\x00\x01@2\x01\x02:\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00\x01M7\x07\x0c\x0c\x06\x1c\x0e=\x03\x04\x01\x01#h\x0e\x06\x0e%\x02\x00\t\x18\x02\x01'
b'\x1d\x03\x00\x05\x08\x05\x08\x183\x0c\x02\x12<\x1e\x12$<\x08\x04\x147\x11\x01\rz\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x18\x06\x17f.\x03\x03\r[\x0c\x07\x182\x0f\n5C\x19\x11,\\\x11\x03\rz\x1a\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0b3\x03\x04%z6\x08\x02\x01B5*O#\x0b\x07\x188NzZ\x1c\x04\x02\x05[\x13"\x1c\x11\x05!)\x05\x0b1L\x0c\x00\x00\x03\x1d:zo\x13\x03\x01\x02@\\S5%\t\x07\x03\x0b\x07-^,\x06\x05\x05\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0bQ\x13\x05\x03\x00\x00\x00\x1cj\x087\x02\x01\x00\x02\x0b\x1fDw\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01S\x05\x01\x03\x03\x00\x02\x19!\x0b\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06E$j\x03\x01\x00\x02\x0e@)\x83\x0c\x00\x04\x04\x00\x00\x1c\x01\x01Ke\x01\x01\x02\x02\x00\n0)\x01\x07\x19\x03l\x83\x1e\x00\x00\x02\x10\x0e\x83q\x01\x00\x08\x03\x01\x05\x00\x00?j\x0c\x0c\x01\x00\x00E\x83M\x04\x01\x00\x00\x0b\x83\x83\x00\x00\x03\x02\x00*M\x08\x00\x03\x14\x10\x04\x0c\x01\x0b\x1b\x15\x04\x1cW\x05\x01\x03*N\x10\x12\x1aa\x02\x00\x00\x01\x03\x02}H\x01\x00\x00\r\x17\x0ca\x03\x00\r&\x04\x05&.\x04\x03\x01\t\x14\x1c7\x17}\x1e\x00\x00\x00\t\t,}\x1b\x00\x01\n\x16\x04#\x00\x00=}\x07\x01\x01\x00\x04\x08Dc\x01\x00\x04\x02}r\x17\t\x00\x00\x01\x05z<\x05\x03\x0c\x06\x01\x06\x02\x17\x1eA\x14\x16\x06\x00\n>}^\x05\x02\x00\x00 }}\x1d\x0c\x04\x00\x00\x0e&\t\x03\x1b\x0c\x00\x01M6\x03\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01"/I\x1b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cZw\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x1bQ\x06\x00\x00\x00w"\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0bw6E,\t\x01\x01\x13\n\x1b=Q%;\x1a\x04\tD+[+\x1b\x07\x00w\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01Hw\x02\x02\x11!\x04\x08w\x04\x11;)QC$\x14\x1bl\'\x01\x04\'\x1e\x02\x17\x0c\x02\x03\x02\x00\x00\x19\x1a\x00\x00\x02\x03\x01-w\x01\x04\r\x07\x04\x1dw1\x01\x0b\t\x00\x00Bs\x01'
b'\x06\x11\t\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x16Av\r\x00\x00\x04\x0b\x01\x05\x917\x00\x02\x0c\x0f\x00\x03-\x10\x01\x02\x07\x02Q\x14\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x91JS\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x06\x11\t\x91\x820\x0f\x00\x01\x00\x02AQ<;\x0c\x00h\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x91\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x1d\x06\x08+]"\x03\x03\x00\x00"trD\x04\x00I\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x91\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\r\x15\x03\x0c\x13\x08\x05\x0c\x02\x00\x03>L\x06\x01\x05\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x07\x1d\x14\x1f\x05\x00\x00\x00,\x9d$\t\xa6\x0f\x00\x02\x03!\x11#9\x04\x01\x0e\x10\x05\x01\x06\x02\x00\x00\x01\x0fA.0\x13\x03\x00\x0e6[\x0f\x08\xa6\x11\x00\x01\x01\x02\x02)`\x05\x00\x0e?\x0c\x00\x07\x07\x01\x02\x05\x05\t\x11\x0f\x19\n\x06$\x17\x04\x03\x03\xa6!\x06\x07\x05\x00\x00\x12g\x0b\x01\x047\x18\x03\x05\n\x0c\x1f\r\x00\x00\x00\x01\x1bZa\x11\x03\x00\x00\x01\xa6\x89b.\x12\x00\x00\r?\x03\x01\x13%\x07\x02\x08\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1cG4\x06\x01\x01\x01\x03yz)\x10\x01\x02\x01\x01\x12zz:\x00\x00\x01\t\x04\x07b\x01\x01\x01\x00\x045Z\x15\x01\x04\x04\x03\x04GQ\na\x0c\x03\x02\x01\x052vz\n\x00\x02\x1d\x15\x04e\x02\x15&\n\x07\x06\x03\x01\x01$@\x0e\r\x03\x01\x01Xs(\x03\x01\x00\x00\x04z^\x01\x02\x1e\x14\x04\x12\x04-8\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02$f,\x1d\x02\x00\x00T[\x19\r\x0b\x05\x01\x019/\x00\x00\x06-\x0b\x02\x86\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x86\x03\x00\x01\x03\x04\x01\x08\x00\x00\x07\x05\x03\x04\x02\x02\x00\x00\x04\x03\x01\x0e\x16\x01\x86\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x86\x0b\x00\x02\x0b\x02\x00\x05\x01\x02\x03\x08\x14\t\x04\x03\x00\x00\x019]W5\x01\x86\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x1c\x86\x0b\x00\x01\x07.f"\x01\x01\x02\x06\x07O\x86\x03\x00\x00\x01]@=\x86\x04\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\'\x16\x04\x00\x00\x005\x86-\x03\x0c\x15\x02\x009\x86\x01\x00\x00\x10\x07\x00\x17E\x00'
b'\x80$(\x07\x00\x00\x00\x07(.\x83(\x00\x00\x00\x03\x07\x04\x83r\x00\x00\x03(!\x01/b\x00\x00\x00b\x83 \x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x83%>!\t\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00ET\x08\x01\x01\x01\x0f\x010\x83\x03\x01\x00!\x83t\x18\x00\x00\x00\x02\x12~\x1b\x00\x12\x13\x0e9,\x00\x00\x00\x07\x15\x13.\x06\x00\x00\x03\x10\x0b&\x12\x02\x152\x15\x00\x01\x02\x0e\x11\t\x03\x01\x01\x01\x0fX \x02\x05\x05\x00\x01\x13m\x0c\x03\x05\x04\x00\x01\x16%\x05\x03\x08\x00\x00\x00\x17\x1e\x02\x04\x12\x03\x00\x00\tD\x1e\x0b\x06\x03\x01\x01\x03R\xabh\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xab\x04\x0f\x01\x00\x00\x05\x0c\x08\x05\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x1a\x16\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\t\'\xabH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01|\x02\x02\x00\x01\x02\x04\n\x04\x0c\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\r\x145\x1b\x05\x01\x00\x00\x07\x17\xab\xa2\x00\x00\x00\x03\x10\x1b\x00\x02\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x01\r\x14\x05\x00\x00\x03\x07\x072r\x15\x00\x00\x00\x02\r\xa8c\x0b\x01\x00\x13@-\'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x12\x89$\x03\x00\x00\x01\x89\x88\x88\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x89/M\x00\x00\x00\x00\x023\x89\x05\x00\x00\x00\x03\x06 #\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00B|-\x14\x07\x03\x00\x00\x1d,\x19\x89\x07\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05[\x01\x06\x05\x00\x01\x05\x04\x01\x08\r\x08\x00\x00\x01\x07\x03\x1f\x15\x04\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x89F\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0b\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02/\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x89n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x04\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00G\n\x00\x00!\x01\x00\x00\x04\x02\x01\r\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00^\x1a\x12\n\x06\x13\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x02\rX\x13\x03\x02\x10\x02\x02\x02\x04\x04\n\n\x8e\t\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02G\x11 7\x1e!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03-A]\x04\x01\x00\x0b%7\n\x02\x01\x04\x02\x8e\x8e\r\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x04"\x8e(\x04\x00\x01\x01\x00\x08\x8e\x8e\x08\x00\x06\x03\x01n\x8e\x1a\x00\x00\x02\x00\x1c\x8e4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b"\x80\x16\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x0c-T&\x0c\x11\x07\x1275\x1b8\x08\x07\x03\x0e9\x0b\x05\x18\x11$\x1b\x01\x06\x01\x80a\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x03\x80Y\x0e!L\x1b\x06\x073\x1d\x05\t\x1a\x0f\x11]!\x11$\x1f\x04\x00\x1aB\x80!\x00\x01\x01\x00\x02!e\x05\x00\x00iZ\x1b1\x04\x00\x00\x00.+]Y\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x80fn\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01I\x17\x00\x01\x08 #\x11@\x00\x00\x00\x1f3\x1d$\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x16F\x07;\x1d\x02\x00\x00\n\n\x14\x0c\x0e\x01\x00\x06=I\x10I\x02\x00\x00\x05\x15 U`\x02\x00\x01\x02\r\x04//\x03\x02\x01\x02\x1f*%\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03UU\x1aw\x16\x00\x00\x00\x084tw\x0f\x01\x04\x02\x06\x077\x03\x08kG\x03\x08\n\x04\x03-w+\x05\x0f\x0b\x04wwE\x04\x00\x01\x06\x0bdR\x07\x07\n\x04\x05\x0c\x01\x1ae+\x00\x00\t\x01\x01?w0\x00\x06\x19\x05\x15iw\t\x00\x02\x07\x08\x0b4\x11\x05\n\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x8c\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00\x041\x8c\r-\x01\x03!\x18\x11\x8c{&\x01\x08\x1f\x04\x01\x10Q\x03\x00\x00\x01\x01\x1cJ\x06\x10\x02\x01\x02\x01\x0fE\x17\x8c\x06\x01\x03\x01\x04\x1f\\\x8c\x08\x11/\x03\x00\x04K\x06\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x02\x0f\x08\x08\x04\x00\x00\x01\t\x8cL\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x11\x8c8\x02\x11\x04\x00\x00!\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x1d\x1f\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08M\x8c\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x027\x87\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02 \x10\x00\x077\x05\x02\t}}\x02\x02\x15\x11\x03\x00\x15'\x04\x12\x15N*\x04\x1b\t\x06\x0b\x05\x0c\r\x17d\x12\x00\x01\x1d\t\x12-}M\x04\x05`(\x02\x17\t<5\tKB\x18\x05\x10\x1f\x19\x03\x08%\x1e\x14Z\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x0bV}\x07\x03\x02+\x18\x1b}\x11!\x14\x074DT\x15\x01\x02\x05\x032}:\x03\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x050=\x00\x00\x00\x03\x10\x1e}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1apM\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00%^\x0b\x01"
b'+!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x7f\x19\x06\x01\x01\x00\x02\x00\x1f8\x7f\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16`\x03\x00\x00\x00\x7fM\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01a\x7f\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x19+x\x02\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00H\x7f\x02\x01\x00\x00\x7f\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x7f\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x03\x07<\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03G\'\x04\x00\x00\x0c\x1e\x03\x19d\x0f?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005R\x00\x00\x00\x02\x1a\x14\x7f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x7f)\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x024j \x01\x06\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x0c\x01\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00=\x0c\x01\x00\x08\x0c\x00\x04\x9a*\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x01\n\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x08\x04\x02\x08\x0e\x01\x00i\x10\x01\x02\x0e\x14\x03\x11\x9a\x1c\x00\x00\x0b\x05\x000\x00\x0c\x96%\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04Bq\r\x08\x00\x00C\x14\x10\x17\x07\t\x00\x10\x9a\x1c\x01\x01\t\x08\x03>\x00\x06\x887\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00y\x9a\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x0b>\x9a\x04\x02\x00\x03\x9a\x18\r\x06\x00\x03\x03!(\x06\x00\x02\x16\r\x00\x01\x95&\x0fH\x1d\x01\x00\x04\x01\x05L\x95\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00CW\x1a\x03\x00\x00\x00V\x0e\x00\x00"\x16\x03\x07\x95\x03\x03\x05\x1a\x06\x01\x1d\x0f\x0f8>\x11\x03\x02\x02\x008F\x15\x05\x0c\x03\x00B\x10\x00\x00!\x1f\x03\x07\x95\x04\x01\x02\x14\x13\x02\x1f\x14\x08\x03\x02\x029\x14\x02\x00\x01\x01\x00\x02\x954\x00\x1e\x01\x00\x00\x17\x1b\x05\x04\x95\x00\x00\x00\x11>\x11 \x06\x00\x00\x00\x01\x95>\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x862\x00\x8d\x05\x05#\x01\x00\x00\'8\x03?\x8d\x08\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x03r\x8d\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07?\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8d/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x80\x11\x1d@\x02\x06\x05\x12\x04\x01\x8d\x8d\x01\x01\x08\x05\x00\x19\x8d7\x00\x01\x0b\x00\x8d7\x00\x00\x01\x00\x007T\x13\x03\x05\x04\x04\x03\x17\t\x02\x05\x04\x05\x02\x05\x08\x00\x01\x0c\x05\x04\x02\n\x01\x8d=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0fA\x11\x01\x02\x04\x02\x01\x07\x08\x04\x00\x02\x05\x01\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x02\x03\x01\x00\x00'
b'c)K\x0c\x00\x00\x00\'\x16\x0b\x86a\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x01\x86\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x86\t\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00H\x86\t,\x19\x07\x0b\x04#\x00\x02uO\x02\x05\x0c\x05\x00\x01\x86w\x00\x00\x06\x05\x86\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x86\x12\x00\x01\x10\x10\x01\x11\x01\x02\x01\x01\x03\x04\x03\x01\x01\x02\x03\x02\x00\x00\x05\x05\x84[\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x02J%\x01\x01\x0e\x06\x00\x03\x02\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x014\x1c\x1a\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x14\x11xE\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00fB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x18\x00\x00\x00\x00x\n\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0bx\x07E)\x03\x01\x00\t\x00\x00x\\\x02\x02\x06\x01\x00\x00xd\x00\x00\x03\x01x\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04x\x01\x00\x03\x0c\x1c\x03\x02\x00\x00\x01\x02\x0fxg\x07\x00\x00\x0c\x07\x00\x0cxHx\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05j\x01\x00\x00S<\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00Hx#\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06*(/\t\x03\x1e\x16\x00\x00\n\x98K$\x0f\x02\x00\x00\x01\x05\x08t\'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03[\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00a\x07\x06-\x13\x00\x00\x14\x98\x08\x01\x14\x0c\x01\x02\x19\x0c\x01\x04\x03\x02\x04\x05\x04\x04\x05\x08\x02\x02\r\x11\x03T\x08\x04 $\x00\x00\x07\x98\x03\x01\r(\x03\x02 \x14\x02\x01\x04\x10e"\x07\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x98\x89\x02(\x01\x00\t"\x01\x00\x03\x98\x02\x00\x0586\x04\x0f\x10\x00\x00\x00.\x98&\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\tp.\x00)9\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&wu%\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\nwk\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x0489\x02\x03\x02\x00w1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08wD\x18\x17\x05\x02\x00\x07\x07\x16\\J\t\x05\x13\x06\x01\x1dwH\x00\x02\x1b\x07w\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1fw\x1c\n\x08\x0f\x02\x0eQ\x05\x04"\';\x0c3\x1c\x03\x0e2\x05\x01\x05M\x14V\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?6\x00\x00\x00\x01\rBw\x01\x01\x12\r\x05\x07p[\x00\x0b\'\x03\x00\x06G\x0f'
b'\x10$\x03\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0b[A\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18|\x18\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07m\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00oO\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x03n|p\x06\x01\x00\x00\x06\x01-|\x11\x07\x15\x06\x00\x00\x0bw,\x02\x0f\x18\x03|\x0f\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00+|\x15\x0c\x02\x0c\x15\x0cb\x0e\x0e\x0f\x04(|\x1b\n\x06\x0b\n\x08\t1&\x04-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x019,\x00\x00\x00\x01\x17L|M\x12\x01\x00\tT9\x1f\x0e\n\x02\x03\x13Y\t\x02T\x03\x00\x01&5\x07\x1a$\t\x03\x04jc\x04\x17\x15\x0b\x08$\x0e\x01\x01\x0c\x00\x00\x03!\x0b\x01\x01\x00Y$\x03\x03mR\x03\x02@\x07\x02\x03<G\x01#m\x07\x08N\x0c\x00\x004\x00\x00\x02F\x14\x01\x01\x00F\x18\x05\x04m]\x08\x0604.%\x1e\t\x00\x08m#\x13G\x06\x00\x00M\x10\x01\tm(\x00\x00\x1121\x03\x00\x07$\x08\x05JmmW\x01\x00\x00\x00&\x14Hm\x04\x00\x00*0\x03\x08`\x12\x00\x00.\x82\x17\x00\x01\x13\x18\x00\x02e\x0b\x00\x00f\x82\x04\x02\x82\x1f\x00\x00\x17@\x17"\x0b\x06\x00\x00\x0c\x82\x1f\x05\x82\x1e\x00\x03k4\x00\x02L\t\x00\x00\x82x\x02\x03}\x01\x00\x00\tEKC\x01\x00\x00\x00\tbA\x0b\x82\x0b\x00\x00g9\x05\x0c\x1e\x02\x00\x00]?\x03\x04\x11\x04\x00\x00\x07\x0b\x06\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x06\x04\x04\x18\x00\x00\x00\x11\x12\t\x0e\x07\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x11\x05\x04\x0b\x01\x00\x00\x03\x05\x01\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x04\x01\x02\x00\x02\x02\x01\x00\x04\x03\x01\x18\x02\x02\x01\x01\x02\x0f.[\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x89P\x05\x01\x01\x01\x00\x0fK\x00\x02\x0c\t\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x0b\x06\x07\x01\x01\x03\x89\x19\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06(\x89\x1e\x01\x01\x04\x01\x01 \x00\x024F\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cM\x0f\x04\x02\x00\x00\x89\x84/\x02\x01\x02\x00\x07\x89W\x02\x01\x02\x01\x01\x0b\x00\x04\x89O\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x89\x1c\x01\x01\x00\x00\x0c\x89\x89\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f=\x04\x00\x00\x02\x01\x00'
b'P6\x0f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01.:wM\t\x01\x00\x01\x02\x04&w\x13\x00\x00\x03\x0f\x03+C\x02\x00\x00\x0ew\x17\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x1ew\x0c\x04#\x0e\x02\x04\x10\x02\x00\x03wM\x01\x02\x03 \x03\x0eF\x15\x00\x02:w,\x02\x02\x05\x03\x002p\x13\x05\x05\x02\x1a\x18<\x03\x00\x05=,mc\x06\x03\x00\x00*2A;\x10RS\x04\x01\x06\x13\x05\x04\x1c\x18\x03\x00\x0fwA\x08\x01\x00\x00\x04\x08wk\x08\x02\x00\x00\x03\x05\x1e\'\x08\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x0e\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x03\x04@*\x17\x16\x07\x00\x00\x04\x07\x0c\x101*\x01\x00\x00\n\x18\x1c\t\x02\x00\x00\x01\n\n\x15\x1b\n\x00\x00\x01\x86,\x11+\x17\x00\x01+L\x0f\r\x86\x86\x01\x00\r"\x1f$&\x16\x01\x00\x01\x05\x14 #%\x02\x00\x00\x86+\x1d\x13\x0e\x00\x00=\x86\n\t\x86\x86\x00\x00&\x15\x16/-\r\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x866\x04\x00\x00\x00W^e%\x01\x00\x00\x0f\x81\x0b\x0c5h\x00\x00\x1bz!\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03K0iO\x01\x00\x00\x07\t\x11~x\x03\x00\x00\x01\x06[]\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00~#\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0b~ \x0e\n\x03\x00\x00\x1e9\x04D)8\x05\x03\x1b\x07\x0e&\x1b\x10\x01\x01\x0b~3\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14~5!\r\x02\x01\x01\x19!\n\x11%:\t\x06\x14\x19\x00\x00\x13(\x05\x05\x1ba\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x026x\x16\x06\x03\x02\x0cMF\x06\x02\x03\x11\x1eB~\x07\x08\x00\x00\x05\x13+F :\x11\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00\x06\x88J\x10\x03\x00\x00\x00\x08\x05\n!\x0e\x03\x00\x03\x03\x00\x01\x02\t0\x0c\x00\x01g\x0e\x00\x03\x03\x03\x01\x0f\x884\x08\n\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x08\x05\x0e,\x13\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x16n\x10\x00\x00d\x07\x00\x02\x03\x04\x04\x1a\x884\x0e\x08\x03\x06\x0e\\\x07\t\x151\x1aV,\t\x00\x00\x01\x0eS~$\x00\x19\x01\x00\x02\x04\t\x0e\x1aH\x05\x00\x00\x02\x17\x88\x88\x01\x00\x00\x01\x06\x88\x88\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04kS\x00'
```

I want to successfully turn this into an array of integers, I tried many things but nothing worked.
I also want to read the file line by line if possible (i dont know the size of each line).

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/how-to-convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int

Comment: If you mean the "unpack" solution it throws 'struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes' and the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376438/struct-error-unpack-requires-a-buffer-of-4-bytes doesnt help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert (bytes to numbers and back), you can use different methods:

```
def int_to_bytes(x: int) -> bytes:
    return x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')

def int_from_bytes(xbytes: bytes) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(xbytes, 'big')

s = b'&\x12\x04\x01\x04\x06\x05\x01S*\x11\x05\x03\x01\x00\x04\x01!3+\x0c\x00\x00\x00N\x04\n0\x13\x01\x00\r[2\x10\x0b\n\x03\x00\rwN$\x16\x01\x00\x00\x0e:NKN>\x00\x00\x01u\x00\x049w\x05\x00\x1a\\?\x02\x04\x04\x04\x15\x1bw"\x0f\x12\x00\x05LCR\x16\x04&ICw2H\x00\x00\x14wP\x1a\x1e\r\x06\x00\x00\x00\x048\x19\x07\x01\x01\x01\x01\x0ew\'\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03$w\x17\x04\x01\x01\x00\x0c-1\nn2\x04\x01\x00\x00\x01\x0fD$.4\x01\n9\x1d\x00\x00%1\x02\nj*\x01\x01\n\x0b\x02\x01WD\x7f%\x02\x01\x00\x00\x01\x06\x7f"0>\r\x12\x10\x05\x00\x00&]W#\x08\x01\x00\x00\x05\x1b7\x14\x19\x11\x7f\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x01\x03\x19}\x06\x00\x031T&\x11\x00\x00\x00\x024\x7fM\x04\x00\x00\x00\n,"$\x0eI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1dN\x1b\x00\x00\x07\x1f<\x7fJ\x00\x00\x00\x0e4`J\n\x00\x00\x00\x03\x02\x04,+f\x1c\x01\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00U\'\x18F\x0b\x00\x00\x0b\x0b\t\x19\x1b\x01\x03\x1e2\x04)\x15\x02\x08\x11\x12\x03\x7f\x1f\x01\x02\n\x01\x00\x07\x7f,&o\r\x04\x00\x05\x1f Cp\x18\x06\x0b\x0c\x1dV-\x05\x06\n\x06\x06\x7f\x03\x00\x01\x05\x02\x03:\x7f\x02\x02\x11\n\x18\\_\x16\x0c\x10=\x0e\x1er\r\x13\x0b\x08\x05\x0cFZ\t\x1c\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06&\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x7f[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x7f\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002n\x02h\x1a\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x1c=3\x0f\x11\x05\r\x13\x1d D$$\n\x05\x06\x01\x00\x03\'"\n\x05\x08\x01\x84\x18\x03\x00\x00\x01\x04\x07\x84=\x19\x17\x06\x00\x01\x07=2\r\x1f\x11\n\x0c\x16\x02\x0e\x1aB\x17\x0f(\x04\x84\x11\x01\x00\x00\x01\x03\x12\x84\x17\x06\x05\x05@\x17\x1a\x14\t\x03\x07\x05\x84\x84\x0b\x01\x04\x06\x05\x01h\x84\x11q\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\r(?\x02\x01\x00\x04\x84J\'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x848\x03\x02\x03\x04\x02\x03\x18\x1a\x06'

print( int_from_bytes(s) )
print( int_to_bytes(int_from_bytes(s)))

v = [ x for x in s ] # integer list 
print( v ) 

s = b''.join([(x).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big') for x in v]) # integer list to bytes
print( s )
```